# GIT: checkout to another branch while rebasing

Tags: git

I'm in the middle of rebasing a local branch on a remote one, with tons of conflicts.
I need to move to another local branch to check something, then return to this one and continue rebasing without losing the work i've already done on resolving some conflicts.
Any hints on how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Best way: clone the repository to another folder

Comment: Did you try stashing ?

Comment: first use `git rebase --abort` this will abort the current rebase and you are back to your branch with no conflicts and then you can simply squash your commits of your branch to make a single commit. It will save you from a lot of trouble for resolving conflicts multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

I dont think this is possible in the same repository but you can always clone it.

```
 git clone path/to/local/repo c/tempRepo -b development
```

Comment: If you're planning to clone a repo multiple times, you should consider using [git-worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree)